# Understanding recursive canSum function

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function, which, given a number and a list of numbers returns if the number can be made out of the
numbers in a list, where numbers can be used as many times as needed:

```
def canSum(target_sum, numbers, memo = {}):
    if target_sum in memo:
        return memo[target_sum]
    if target_sum == 0:
        return True
    if target_sum < 0:
        return False

    for n in numbers:
        remainder = target_sum - n
        if canSum(remainder, numbers) == True:
            memo[target_sum] = True
            return True, memo

    memo[target_sum] = False
    return False,memo
```

It should return `True` and `False` depending if the `target_sum` can be made by adding any numbers any amount of time in the `numbers` list.

For example `canSum(4, [2])` should return `True` because `2+2` is 4 and so on.
However I can't understand where is my mistake, all of the below should return `True`.

```
canSum(4,[2])
# (False, {2: True, 4: False})

canSum(4,[2,1])
# (False, {2: True, 1: True, 3: True, 4: False})

canSum(4,[1,2])
# (True, {1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True})

canSum(10,[2])
# (False, {2: True, 4: False, 6: False, 8: False, 10: False})

canSum(10,[2,3])
# (False, {2: True, 1: False, 4: False, 3: True, 6: False, 5: True, 8: False, 7: True, 10: False})
```

Also, is there a difference or a need to pass `memo` to the recursive function call? Which does not seem to make any difference.

```
 if canSum(remainder, numbers) == True: # -> if canSum(remainder, numbers, memo) == True:
    memo[target_sum] = True
    return True, memo
```

Comment: Damn, I just wanted to check how `memo` is built, that caused the error, without it everything works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider when you call `canSum(0, [2])`, the function will be return literal `True`. and `if canSum(0, [2]) == True` condition's will be satisfy. but when you call `canSum(2, [2])`, the function will be return a tuple of `(True, {2: True})` and `if canSum(2, [2]) == True` condition's won't be satisfy. So when you call `canSum(4, [2])`, the function will return `(False, {2: True, 4: False})`.

You have to return in same format for every calls. I think this will be work.

```
def canSum(target_sum, numbers, memo={}):
    if target_sum in memo:
        return memo[target_sum], memo
    if target_sum == 0:
        return True, memo
    if target_sum < 0:
        return False, memo

    for n in numbers:
        remainder = target_sum - n
        if canSum(remainder, numbers)[0]:
            memo[target_sum] = True
            return True, memo

    memo[target_sum] = False
    return False, memo
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is really any benefit of writing this line: `memo[target_sum] = True`. I think its going to be executed only once and there is no point in storing it in memo. Somebody please tell me if I am right or missing something.